# React Date Range Picker

Tags: reactjs, react-daterange-picker

I have a project am creating and I want to have a react-date-range calendar in the project. Problem is when displaying the calendar the dates are not aligned with the days. How can I[enter image description here align them properly.

[Calendar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSWjG.png)

Calendar days and dates not aligned properly

Answer (score 1):

react-date-range can be installed with `npm`, by the following command:

```
npm install react-date-range
```

First, styles and theme file must be imported:

```
import 'react-date-range/dist/styles.css'; // main css file
import 'react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css'; // theme css file
```

Then, import one of the 4 standalone components: `DateRange`, `DateRangePicker`, `Calendar`, `DefinedRange`

The best way is to follow [documentation](https://hypeserver.github.io/react-date-range/)

Comment: thank you, it's a well organized answer

Comment: Have done all that, still getting same output

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have the css imports in your code

```
import 'react-date-range/dist/styles.css';
import 'react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css';
```

Comment: I have the CSS imports but it still behaves like this

Answer (score 0):

Consider including this style; from what I recall, it's effective:

```
.react-datepicker__time-container   .react-datepicker__time  
.react-datepicker__time-box   ul.react-datepicker__time-list {  
     padding: 0; 
}
```

Comment: where should I input this style kindly?

Comment: the file where react-date-range is called in the related CSS code @SamsonNjuguna